# Пробельные символы

Tags: c++builder, c++

Как удалить пробельные символы в средине строкы? в С++билдер

Answer (score 2):

Используя stl

```
s.erase(std::remove(s.begin(), s.end(), ' '), s.end());
```

Используя boost

```
erase_all(s, " ");
```

Или просто в цикле пройти вдоль строки и скопировать все не пробельные символы в новую строку.